# Ruby syntax error when initiating an array of objects with no parentheses

Tags: ruby

I got this error:

> SyntaxError ((irb):8: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ']')
>
> Person.new "Nick",
>
> (irb):8: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
>
> Person.new "Nick",

When executing the following code:

```
class Person
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end

a = [
    Person.new "Nick",
    Person.new "James"
]
```

I understand how I can fix it, I just wanna know why exactly it happens.

Comment: Before applying @Jagdeep's answer, be sure on change `initalize` to `initialize`.

Comment: Famous, did you get the error when you had the method `initalize` or `initialize`?.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the error is same with both.

Comment: Note the following:  `Person.new "Nick" #=> #<Person:0x00000000bfcea8 @name="Nick">`, whereas `[Person.new "Nick"] #=> SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ']'...`

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "Famous, did you get the error when you had the method `initalize` or `initialize`?" – Since the error is a `SyntaxError`, it *cannot possibly matter* what the name of the method is (unless it is syntactically invalid), since the code cannot be parsed and therefore will never run, and therefore the method will never be called, and therefore, it will never be missing or have the wrong number of parameters.

Comment: That was just a typo in the question description. In the actual code I was using initialize method.

Comment: Good point, @Jörg. Can you explain the behavior I reported in my previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is:

> I understand how I can fix it, I just wanna know why exactly it happens

---

Without the parentheses it is ambiguous: it could equally mean

- `[Person.new("Nick"), Person.new("James")]`, or
- `[Person.new("Nick", Person.new("James"))]`

Comment: Do you think `Person.new("Nick", Person.new("James"))]` would work?

Comment: Not given the class definition we can see... but it's a syntax error; while parsing, the language doesn't know how many parameters Person.new wants. Note the question is "why is this an error?", not "how do I fix this?"

Comment: _while parsing, the language doesn't know how many parameters Person.new want_, indeed, it does, see the local table first argument value `size`. Second piece of code just introduces a NoMethodError.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because ruby is confused in interpreting spaces between `Person.new` and its argument(s). Use parenthesis `()` around name:

```
a = [
  Person.new("Nick"),
  Person.new("James")
]
```

Comment: "I think" is an opinion, not an answer. Dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

if you run `a = ["hello" "there", "some" "where"]` it will return `=> ["hellothere", "somewhere"]`

maybe that happens because it tries to attach string to class!

Comment: Good point. I think that's a good reason for me to use parentheses in ruby more often.